# Spring MVC, correct response to post request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have some problem with POST request.
When user clicks to button for logIn, the page (localhost:8080/) sends to server POST request (localhost:8080/authorization). If authorization is unsuccessful then a browser opens getting page in new tab!!!!
I cannot understand why it happens, because if authorization is successful then the browser  updates current tab only.

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/authorization", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String authorization(@ModelAttribute(AUTH_USER) 
        @Valid AuthorizationForm authData, BindingResult result,
        Model model){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute(REG_USER, trUserService.getSignUpDTO());
        return "index";
    }
    if(!securityService.logIn(trUserService.getUser(authData), 
            authData.getPassword())){
        result.rejectValue("password", "v.registrationform.password.notfound");
        model.addAttribute(REG_USER, trUserService.getSignUpDTO());
        return "index";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Also i noticed that when login is successful server sends Request Code:'302 Found' otherwise Request is 'Code:200 Ok'.

Why it happens and what can i do that after the successful authorization a browser would open the response in current tab.

Comment: did you set target on the html form element?

Comment: No i didn't. the button looks like:
 <input type="submit" class="inputsubmit green" name="Login" value="Вход">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment contains the answer, but answering here so you can close the question.

Looks like you set the "target" attribute on the form to something you didn't want. Change or remove the attribute, and things will come out rosy.